# Posting array in with HttpURLConnection in java

Tags: java, arrays, httpurlconnection

We have this code which we are using to post data from an Android app to a .Net Rest service. One of the fields that the backend is and array. Swagger specifies it as

> modelbinding  Array[integer]

How should we put the value array of integers in the urlParameters so we can post it?

```
String urlParameters = "field1=abc&field2=def";

URL url = new URL(targetURL);

connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setUseCaches (false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

// Send request
writer = new DataOutputStream (connection.getOutputStream ());
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(writer, "UTF-8"));
bufferedWriter.write(urlParameters);
bufferedWriter.flush ();
bufferedWriter.close ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json format  is the best way to send data. you can convert your data in json array then json array to string. Now your string(represented in json formate) can easily be sent.

Comment: We've tried sending json but we have some issues there also. Like the above it's working except for one array typed field in the backend. Do you have any solution if we want to send the data like this?

Comment: @MathiasR, can you please tell me what type of issue you have encountered in sending json data?

Comment: Ended up converting all payloads to json